# Bisimplicial spaces as a coequalizer of maps between "simpler" bisimplicial spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, simplicial-stuff, grothendieck-topology

From a bisimplicial space $T$, one can consider the simplicial spaces $p \mapsto T_{pp}$, $p \mapsto | q \mapsto T_{pq}|$, and $q \mapsto |p \mapsto T_{pq}|$, where $| \cdot|$ denotes geometric realisation. In a lemma (used in proving Theorems A and B) [on page 10 of 'Higher Algebraic K-theory I'](https://sma.epfl.ch/%7Ehessbell/topo_alg/Quillen.pdf), Quillen gives a proof that these three simplicial sets all have coincidental realisations, but I'm having touble understanding the proof.

First of all, he claima that any $T$ has a canonical presentation of the form
$$     \amalg_{(r,s) \rightarrow (r′,s′)}h^{r′,s′} \times T^{r s}  \rightrightarrows \amalg_{(r,s)} h^{r,s} 
 \times T^{r s} \rightarrow T$$,
where $h^{rs} =hom_ { \Delta} (-,r-) \times hom_{ \Delta} ( -,s-)$, (with the hom-sets having the discrete topology).

The fact that it is canonical comes from its functoriality in $T$. To show that our diagram is in fact a coequalizer diagram it suffices to show that it is an objectwise coequalizer diagram. But at this point I don't know how to do this.

Once we have the claim, I understand how the proof continues.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Quillen gives as a reference a paper from Tornehave, On BSG and the symmetric groups, but I can not find it anywhere. Does someone know if I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

I certainly respect going back to primary sources. But, in this case, it's helpful to remember that a LOT has been written about bisimplicial sets since Quillen's 1973 paper. For example, a reference that spells out the claim about being a coequalizer is [Goerss, Jardine Simplicial Homotopy Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0346-0189-4), Lemma 5.17 in Chapter IV (bisimplicial sets). Another reference is Lemma 5.3.1 in [Hovey's book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf) (the claim about being a coequalizer is half a page above the proof of the lemma). More references can be found at [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+simplicial+topological+spaces), which also proves the Lemma from Quillen's paper, as [Lemma 3.4](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+simplicial+topological+spaces). While Quillen's proof is hands-on, the nLab proof is nice and clean, using that geometric realization is a co-end (and adjoint to Sing(-)), that the diagonal pops up when you compute the mapping space, and the universal property. See also Jeff Smith's answer at [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97732/realization-of-a-bisimplicial-set), which proves the same result by recognizing things as homotopy colimits (and using the universal property).